Python curses won't work properly in cmd or powershell
I'm trying to display big ascii text with curses, but it only works in the Visual Studio Code terminal for some reason.
Visual Studio Code terminal displays the text correctly
But when I try to run the program in powershell it cuts off the start of the text for some reason, and when I run it in cmd, it just displays a square of question marks.
The windows powershell terminal has the letters cut off at the start, replaced by empty space, and the cmd terminal just displays a box of question marks
What's going on and how do I fix it?
main.py:
import os, curses, time
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    HEIGHT = curses.LINES
    WIDTH = curses.COLS

    logo = []
    with open("logo.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as dataFile:
        logo = dataFile.readlines()
    
    for i in range(len(logo)):
        stdscr.addstr(logo[i])

    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()


curses.wrapper(main)

logo.txt:
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＃　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＃　　　＃＃　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
　　＃　　＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃　　　＃＃　　＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃　　　　　＃＃＃＃＃　　　　　　　＃＃＃＃　　
　　　＃　＃　　＃　＃＃　＃＃　　　　＃　　＃　　　　　　　　　　　　＃＃　　　＃＃　　　　　＃　　　＃＃　
　　　　　＃　　＃　＃＃　　　　　　　　　＃　　　　　　　　　　　　＃＃　　　　　＃＃　　　＃＃　　　　　　
　　　　　　　＃＃　＃＃　　＃　　＃　　＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃　　　＃＃　　　　　　　＃　　　＃＃　　　　　　
　＃＃　　　＃＃　　　＃＃＃＃　　＃＃　　　＃　　＃　　　＃　　　＃＃　　　　　　　＃＃　　＃＃＃　　　　　
　　　＃　＃＃　　＃　　　　　　　　　＃　　＃　　＃　　　＃　　　＃＃　　　　　　　＃＃　　　＃＃＃＃　　　
　　　　　　　　　＃　　　　　　　　　　＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃　　＃＃　　　　　　　＃＃　　　　　＃＃＃＃　
　　　　　＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃　　　　＃　　＃　　＃　　＃＃　　　＃＃　　　　　　　＃＃　　　　　　　＃＃　
　　　＃　　　　　＃＃　　　　　　　　＃　　＃　　＃　　＃＃　　　＃＃　　　　　　　＃　　　　　　　　　＃＃
　　　＃　　　　＃＃＃＃　　　　　　＃＃　＃＃　　＃　　＃＃　　　　＃＃　　　　　＃＃　　　　　　　　　＃＃
　　＃＃　　　＃　＃　　＃　　　　　＃　　＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃　　　　＃＃　　　＃＃　　　　＃＃　　　＃＃　
　＃＃　　＃＃　　＃　　　＃＃　　＃＃　　＃　　　　　　＃　　　　　　　＃＃＃＃＃　　　　　　＃＃＃＃＃　　
　＃　　　＃　　　＃　　　　　　　＃　　　　　　　＃＃＃＃　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　

I tried debugging by addstr-inging different variations of "A" and "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" instead the ascii font, which worked normally.
I also tried changing the text to become smaller, in case the text got looped or something in the powershell terminal, but the same problem persisted.
Lastly I tried removing the first character for the same reason. The cut-off point seemed to be the same place on the screen, with less text meaning less of the text could peek past the blacked out area.

You have a problem with utf-8 encoded characters and compatibility. By swapping -f and -t in this: $ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -o utf-8 logo.txt  I can go from displaying the above, to a block of ? - back and forth. My understanding of the problem, based on this:: You  need to set curses [affecting stdscr.addstr() ] to appropriately render utf-8 characters regardless of environment. (Tested in Ubuntu Terminal)

import sys;sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8') does the trick for stdout in git Bash (terminal)  on windows.

I am not sure I understand why it has to be so difficult. Maybe you have your reason. Why use curses, if you are using it only to print on stdout very plainly (character after character, and a newline between lines)? If your logo what in the form of the list of coordinates of the #, I would have understood: curses gives some comfort to wmove position on the screen. Or if you used some fancy color (and didn't want to use almost universal but non-portable ANSI \033[... stuff).

You don't even use curses for the only thing you could have used it for (you use some OS specific ugly system to call cls, when curses provides clear for thart.

The rest of your code is just printing the content of logo.txt (while at it, with some system stuff, but I don't encourage it, of course, you could as well have just system('cat logo.txt') or system('type logo.txt')... Not to say you should have. But just to point out that all your code does is displaying the content of logo.txt). Out of curiosity, in your powershell window, what happens if you just type logo.txt? If it prints correctly, then @Hannu solution would probably also works. If not, it may be a matter of settings of the terminal (I know nothing about windows)

... my first comment is wrong; on a second try I'm NOT able to convert it back and forth. logo.txt . So, nonetheless, the stdscr.addstr() function does not do the right thing in just assuming this can be printed in any terminal 'as is'.

in CMD: try C:\> chcp 65001, Then run the python script. I'd guess this does the trick.

None of these work. And type logo.txt gives a lot of "ã"s, "€"s, "ƒ"s, "ï"s and "¼" in a way that kinda looks like the text if i squint

@chrslg I use os to clear because otherwise you can scroll up the terminal to previous code, and I use curses because I'm going to make a whole terminal program. The text being displayed is just me testing as well as a fake boot screen for the terminal program.

I fixed the powershell issue where half the text got cropped by addstr-inging each ＃ separately with coordinates, although this caused a new issue of powershell forgetting how it displays ＃ and instead showing question marks. This also meant that the empty space characters got removed, which means that cmd can display only the question marks for the ＃s.
Both cmd and powershell now display the letters in question marks
Since it seems neither powershell or cmd are able to display the ＃s, I will have to generate text that uses another symbol instead.

One way to BYPASS the problem is to convert the text info characters that are generally printable: this is fairly simple as UTF-8 has most (all?) of the ISO-8859-1 characters in the first 256 codepoints.
$ sed < logo.txt -re 's/\xe3\x80\x80/./g' -e 's/\xef\xbc\x83/#/g' ; echo 
.......................#..............................
..................#...##..............................
..#..##########...##..#########.....#####.......####..
...#.#..#.##.##....#..#............##...##.....#...##.
.....#..#.##.........#............##.....##...##......
.......##.##..#..#..##########...##.......#...##......
.##...##...####..##...#..#...#...##.......##..###.....
...#.##..#.........#..#..#...#...##.......##...####...
.........#..........###########..##.......##.....####.
.....##########....#..#..#..##...##.......##.......##.
...#.....##........#..#..#..##...##.......#.........##
...#....####......##.##..#..##....##.....##.........##
..##...#.#..#.....#..##########....##...##....##...##.
.##..##..#...##..##..#......#.......#####......#####..
.#...#...#.......#.......####.........................

... here at S.O. it looks a bit squished (condensed) as the characters in the monospace font are narrower.
It might need some adaptation to be as nice.

sorry - it is a plain  Python script - the language is perfectly able to encode its output in whatever encoding is appropriate - it doesn't make sense to suggest wrapping another program entirely (and one which by default won't be available on Windows) to re-encode the output, if that is needed.

And HOW is that to be SECURED then? ;-)   I have similar experience with mysterious non-function when transporting data from server to display in varying environments.
